# The Connectionstring Property has not yet been initialize vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, excel, visual-studio-2010

I think the solution is to declare he cnnExcel which I already did but I can't get ride of the error. 
The error line is

```
cnnExcel.Open()
```

and here is the code

```
Public Class Form1
Dim cnnExcel As New OleDbConnection

Public Function GetExcelSheetNames() As String()
    Dim conStr As String = ""
    Dim dt As DataTable = Nothing
    Dim opExcel As New OpenFileDialog
    opExcel.Filter = "(*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|(*.xls)|*.xls"
    opExcel.ShowDialog()
    Dim pathExcel As String = opExcel.FileName
    If pathExcel.Trim = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please select file !")
        Return Nothing
    Else
        Dim Ext As String = pathExcel.Substring(pathExcel.LastIndexOf(",") + 1)
        If Ext.Length = 3 Then
            conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathExcel + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=yes;IMEX=1';"
        ElseIf Ext.Length = 4 Then
            conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + pathExcel + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=Yes';"
        End If
        cnnExcel = New OleDbConnection(conStr)
        cnnExcel.Open()
        dt = cnnExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing)
        If dt Is Nothing Then
            Return Nothing
        End If
        Dim excelSheetNames As [String]() = New [String](dt.Rows.Count - 1) {}
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
            excelSheetNames(i) = row("TABLE_NAME").ToString()
            i += 1
        Next
        cnnExcel.Close()
        Return excelSheetNames
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on 'cnnExcel.Open()` and check the value of conStr. Maybe `LastIndexOf(",")` should be `LastIndexOf(".")` (find last fullstop, not comma).

Comment: Setting a breakpoint and and debugging even a single time would've yielded you the answer.

Comment: Ahhh Thanks Rhys Jones, That fixed the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are initializing the connection-string in the `If...ElseIf`, but it's still uninitialized it means  that both conditions do not match, so `Ext.Length`is neither   `= 3` nor `= 4`. And the reason is that you are using `pathExcel.LastIndexOf(",")` instead of `pathExcel.LastIndexOf(".")`.

However, i'd use [`System.IO.Path.GetExtension`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead:

```
Dim extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(pathExcel)
If extension.Equals(".xls", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
    conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathExcel + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=yes;IMEX=1';"
ElseIf extension.Equals(".xlsx", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
    conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + pathExcel + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=Yes';"
Else ' should not happen with the current OpenFileDialog settings '
    Throw New NotSupportedException("Illegal file-path, it must be either .xls or .xlsx")
End If
```